# Packet sniffing between different applications in same server

Tags: tomcat, packet-capture

I have two different applications in one tomcat. One application performs an HTTP request to the REST API on the second application.

How can I sniff packets (the request)?

This is my development machine, not the production architecture.

Thanks!

Comment: Aside from packet sniffing, you can also enable Tomcat's RequestDumperValve to write out all the request parameters being sent to the target server

Comment: place it in an answer, I did that and solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments, aside from packet sniffing you can try enabling Tomcat's `RequestDumperValve` to write out all the request parameters being sent to the target server.

This will help confirm the data the 2nd server receives and what values are missing

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will do everything you need.

Comment: www.wireshark.org will tell you everything you need to do - it only cares about network packets; if they're 'on the wire', wireshark will read them.